# Python typing for enum type in function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, enumeration, python-typing

I have this python enum

```
from enum import Enum

class TypeItem(Enum):
    ITEM_1 = 'revenue'
    ITEM_2 = 'net_income_after_taxes'
```

I want to use it as a function argument. The function will look something like this;

```
def function_use(type_item: TypeItem) -> None:
    return None
```

`type_item: TypeItem` is probably wrong. What should be the correct typing for `TypeItem` enum?

I am using python 3.7

Comment: "`type_item: TypeItem` is probably wrong" - it isn't

Comment: @ForceBru I'm shocked. I randomly typed the code.

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong? That's right. The type of an enum instance is ... the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer my own question. Thanks to the comments from ForceBru and Georgy, the correct answer is already in the question.

```
def function_use(type_item: TypeItem) -> None:
    return None
```